# How do I prove this limit is 0?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f\in L^{1}(X,\mathcal M, m)$, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n m\{x:|f(x)|\geq n\}=0$$

Comment: The limit of a sequence of sets is a number?

Comment: @GitGud: $m$ is the measure.

Comment: @GitGud No, n times the measure of the set

Comment: Ohh. I didn't know that was a common notation. Thanks. Edit: I just realised it's stated in triplet $(X, \cal M, m)$. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \int_{|f|\ge n}|f|\ge \int_{|f|\ge n}n=n m\{|f|\ge n\}$, it suffices to see that $\displaystyle \int_{|f|\ge n}|f|\to 0$. But, by assumption, $\displaystyle +\infty>\int_X |f|=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n+1>|f|\ge n}|f|$, so the tails of this series approach zero, that is, 
$$ 0=\lim_{k\to+\infty}\sum_{n\ge k}\int_{n+1>|f|\ge n}|f|=\lim_k \int_{|f|\ge k}|f|. $$